# Apply clustering algorithm to group similar actors

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

```
data=pd.read_csv('movie_actor_network.csv', index_col=False, names=['movie','actor'])
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(walks, size=128, window=5)
model.wv.vectors.shape
```

output:

```
(4703, 128)
```

the node_ids

```
node_ids = model.wv.index2word  # list of node IDs
node_embeddings = model.wv.vectors  # numpy.ndarray of size number of nodes times embeddings dimensionality
node_targets = [ A.node[node_id]['label'] for node_id in node_ids]
```

Now using function

```
 def data_split(node_ids,node_targets,node_embeddings):
        '''In this function, we will split the node embeddings into actor_embeddings , movie_embeddings '''
        actor_nodes,movie_nodes=[],[]
        actor_embeddings,movie_embeddings=[],[]
        # split the node_embeddings into actor_embeddings,movie_embeddings based on node_ids
        actor_embedding = [x for i,x in enumerate(node_embeddings) if node_targets[i]=='actor']
        actor_embeddings.append(actor_embedding)
        actor_node = [x for i,x in enumerate(node_ids) if node_targets[i]=='actor']
        actor_nodes.append(actor_node)
        movie_embedding = [x for i,x in enumerate(node_embeddings) if node_targets[i]=='movies']
        movie_embeddings.append(movie_embedding)
        movie_node = [x for i,x in enumerate(node_ids) if node_targets[i]=='movie']
        movie_nodes.append(movie_node)
    
        # By using node_embedding and node_targets, we can extract actor_embedding and movie embedding
        # By using node_ids and node_targets, we can extract actor_nodes and movie nodes
    
        return actor_nodes,movie_nodes,actor_embeddings,movie_embeddings
```

Grader function - 1

```
def grader_actors(data):
    assert(len(data)==3411)
    return True
grader_actors(actor_nodes)
```

Now got error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ee1852cb1df5> in <module>
      2     assert(len(data)==3411)
      3     return True
----> 4 grader_actors(actor_nodes)

NameError: name 'actor_nodes' is not defined
```

How we can fix it?

Comment: Please do **not** write in all-bold (edited).

Comment: So where should `actor_nodes` come from in that function call?

Comment: You have not used your `data_split` function, which returns `actor_nodes` (among other things). So, no surprise here, if this is all your code.

Comment: Please also notice that your issue is irrelevant with the (too long) introduction (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

The function will return you the list within a list, so you would still get an assertion error thrown by def grader_actors(data). If you want your grader_actor function not to throw an assertion error use the below code:

```
def data_split(node_ids,node_targets,node_embeddings):
    '''In this function, we will split the node embeddings into actor_embeddings , movie_embeddings '''
    actor_nodes,movie_nodes=[],[]
    actor_embeddings,movie_embeddings=[],[]
    actor_embedding = [actor_embeddings.append(x) for i,x in enumerate(node_embeddings) if node_targets[i]=='actor']
    actor_node = [actor_nodes.append(x) for i,x in enumerate(node_ids) if node_targets[i]=='actor']
    movie_embedding = [movie_embeddings.append(x) for i,x in enumerate(node_embeddings) if node_targets[i]=='movies']
    movie_node = [movie_nodes.append(x) for i,x in enumerate(node_ids) if node_targets[i]=='movie']

    return actor_nodes,movie_nodes,actor_embeddings,movie_embeddings
```